# Sum of certain numbers till n, n is user defined

Tags: c, for-loop, sum

I wrote a short code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a,b=0,i=0,j=0,sum=0;
    printf("Kerek egy egesz szamot!\n");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    int c[a];
    for(i;i<=a;i++)
    {
        if(i%3==0 || i%4==0)
        {
            c[b++]=i;
        }
    }
    for(j;j<=a;j++)
    {
        sum+=c[b];
    }
    printf("Osszeg: %d",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to sum the value of integers dividable by 3 and 4 till n, where n is user defined. I am unsure why, but I am not getting the right answer. For example, for input 1, I'm getting 8398952 output.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `for(j;j<=a;j++) sum+=c[b];` -> `for(j=0;j<b;j++) sum+=c[j];`

Comment: You could do this without the array. Just add them up as you read them if they meet the criteria.

Comment: Thank you very much @kaylum! One question, do I have to redeclare j=0 inside the loop criteria, or is it enough, I assigned value of 0 to it in the beginning?

Comment: I am pretty new to coding, sometimes I hardly can see how it would be the easiest to do, but I will give a shot to your idea, I got to practice either way! Thanks for the suggestion @RetiredNinja!

Comment: Assigning to 0 at the beginning is fine in your case. But it is more standard and arguably better practice to initialise it as part of the `for` loop. For example, that would allow you to use the same index variable in multiple loops.

Comment: Thanks, it's all clear!